# SHA-256 Hash Crack

Tags: hash, sha-256, attack

Suppose, If a SHA-2 hash does get broken completely with hardly any power, where would it get reported and is there currently a bounty on it?

Comment: Not sure about a bounty, but there's probably a job offer from the NSA/Mossad.

Comment: It's unclear to me what "get broken completely" means. This is mainly an issue because it seems people seems to think that  "completely broken" means that you can "reverse a hash". It is pretty certain that that won't happen. For current standardized hashes (MD5 onwards) only collision resistance has been broken.

Comment: Here my challenge for you `81f02e581681a010bdeee1d40b9f86a5258563c43ae01a5f5f35506abcde73a7` find a pre-image and win a prize.